# Make a network without an internet connection

Tags: networking

If I have a router which is connected to three laptops and a server and there is no internet connection connected to that router then is it possible to still connect within that network of the three laptops and the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, yes. You can connect to any service thats running on any of the systems, either through an ip address, or an internal domain name with a suitable server available - either on your router, or on your server with your clients set up to use it as a DNS.